# How to Obtain Output of Intermediate Model in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm creating a neural architecture using the functional API as follows:

```
x2 = layer1(x1, name='layer1')
x3 = layer2(x2, name='layer2')
m1 = Model(x1, x3)
x5 = layer3(x4, name='layer3')
x6 = TimeDistributed(m1)(x5)
m2 = Model(x5, x4)
```

I've trained m2 (with m1 getting implicitly trained). I can access the output of the layers of m2 (say layer3) by creating an intermediate model:

```
layer_name = 'layer3'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(input=model.input, output=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(input)
```

Since m1 is a nested model, I'm not able to access the layers of m1 through m2. How do I obtain the output x3 (layer2's output) when you use the trained m2 to predict on a new data point.

Comment: Check `model.summary()` and you can see which layers you can access

Answer (score 3):

The key is to first do `.get_layer` on the Model object, then do another `.get_layer` on that specifying the specific layer, **THEN** do .output:

`layer_output = model.get_layer('Your-Model-Object').get_layer('the-layer-contained-in-your-Model-object').output`

Comment: This will create a layer output but it cannot be used to predict the given input.